# Como deixar meu footer sempre embaixo?

Tags: css, footer

Quero deixar o meu footer (http://codepen.io/xmauricioo/full/Zemzvv/) igual o footer dessa pagina (https://codepen.io/cbracco/full/zekgx) "Always on bottom".
Já tentei de tudo e não consigo encontrar o erro. O meu footer fica subindo como se estivesse fixed.
Tentei utilizar esse link [Footer no final do documento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165214/footer-no-final-do-documento), mas nao resolveu. 
Obrigado!!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Footer no final do documento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165214/footer-no-final-do-documento)

Comment: Obrigado pela referência @leofontes, mas não era exatamente o que eu procurava esse link que você passou. Eu também estava com problema do footer subindo junto quando o viewport era diminuido.  Mas com a ajuda do CelsomTrindade consegui resolver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um dos principais motivos de eu não gostar de usar essa técnica, é pelo fato de envolver o `position: absolute`, o que não funciona no caso de um site dinâmico (responsivo), pois depende da definição do `padding-bottom`. O que eu tenho utilizado é o uso de display:flex no `body`. Algo assim:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Deste modo, você declara que o `body` deve ter pelo menos 100% da altura e que o rodapé ficará fixo ao fim da página.

---

No entanto, o seu código atual não está funcionando pois o elemento `.wrapper` também possui a propriedade `position` definida como `absolute`, o que irá ignorar o posicionamento da mesma na página. Basta remover essa propriedade e seu código irá funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado @CelsomTrindade, isso ajudou a resolver o meu problema. Também apaguei o wrapper que só estava atrapalhando. Se quiser ver como ficou: http://codepen.io/xmauricioo/full/Zemzvv/.

Comment: @MauricioSantos bacana, simplificou bastante né? Que bom que pude ajudar! Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de marcar como "aceita" =D

Comment: feito. @CelsomTrindade. Obrigado!

Comment: Melhor solução já encontrada :)

Answer (score -1):

Faz o seguinte, inverte as `positions` do seu `wrapper` e do seu `footer`.

Tenta botar `position: relative` no seu `wrapper` e `position: absolute` no seu `footer`.

Desse jeito o seu footer fica absoluto dentro do seu wrapper.

Comment: Tentei e não funcionou, acabei removendo o wrapper que só estava atrapalhando e sem serventia. Obrigado!.