# Como deixar o Footer sempre no final da pagina?

Tags: html, css, footer, body

Deixo isso abaixo apenas para informação mesmo...
CSS da minha pagina:

```
body{
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;

}
head {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
html{
    height: 100%;

}
div {
    display: block;

}
#container{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;

}
#IGN_SCT{
    height: 100%;
}
.corpo{
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
    min-height:2100px;

}
```

[image: Gostaria que ficasse fixo na parte de baixo da pagina independente do conteúdo acima dela]

Gostaria que ficasse fixo na parte de baixo da pagina independente do conteúdo acima dela

Comment: Já leu essa pergunta: [Footer sempre no final da pagina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205725/5878)?

Comment: .footer { position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;}

Answer (score 1):

```
<footer></footer>
```

Ela tem propriedades semânticas para ser utilizado como rodapé.

Com mais uma isso:

```
footer{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
margin: auto;
bottom: 0;
}
```

E um:

```
position: fixed;
```

Se quiser deixar ele sempre aparecendo na tela.

Comment: Tem? Quais seriam essas propriedades?

Comment: coloque o elemento no seu html e verifica na ferramenta do desenvolvedor ué

Comment: Na minha opinião ele é bom semanticamente e ótimo para motores de busca, por facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Isso com certeza. É que da maneira que havia dito inicialmente deu a entender que o elemento já poderia ficar fixo por si só, sem depender do CSS.

Comment: Desculpa, escrevi rápido e sem pensar, mas não foi o que quis dizer.

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser ele fixo no final da página..

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Se quiser no final da página porem não fixo...

```
 footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

recomendo estudar flex-box.. são propriedades que auxiliam e muito no posicionamento dos elementos na página através do CSS3.. e ainda faz tudo responsivo! obs: não testei os códigos...