# Rodapé "automático"

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um site para indexar links. Tem vezes em que o resultado ocupa menos da metade da página, e vezes que ocupa um enorme scroll. Preciso de um footer que em pouco conteúdo fique grudado em baixo da tela (`bottom: 0;`) porém que se houver scroll de conteúdo, fique na parte de baixo (não poderá ser usado `bottom: 0;`) (um exemplo disso é o sistema de busca do google ou sites de compra). Se alguém souber como fazer isso, por favor ajude. Já foi pesquisado a respeito, porém nada foi encontrado.

Comment: Veja este exemplo que fiz https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205755/3635, se tiver pouco conteudo ele fixa abaixo, se tiver bastante conteudo ele irá acompanhar.

Answer (score 2):

Idêntico ao que sugeri em [**Footer sempre no final da pagina**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205755/3635), basta mudar os seletores pros seus elementos.

Você terá que combinar `position: relative` com `absolute`, não é nada obscuro, basta que o elemento "pai" (no seu caso criei um elemento a mais, o `.main`) esteja em `relative`, ficaria algo como:

> Adicionei um botão para você testar que o rodapé irá acompanhar o conteúdo acaso o scrollbar apareça

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var adicionar = document.getElementById("adicionar");

adicionar.onclick = function () {
    var novo = document.createElement("p");
    novo.textContent = "Foo Bar Baz, " + (new Date());
    content.appendChild(novo);
};
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* é necessário definir o height 100% no html, body ou qualquer elemento que estiver entre o body e o .container */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.main {
    position: relative; /*faz a mágina :)*/
    min-height: 100%; /* define a altura minima*/
    background: #fcfcfc;
}

.main > footer {
   background: #0c0c0c;
   color: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <header></header>
    <div id="content">
         Todo conteúdo vai aqui<br>
         <button id="adicionar">Adicionar conteudo</button>
    </div>
    <footer>Rodapé</footer>
</div>
```